# google charts Dual Y charts and labeling column

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

How is it posible to add **label** in each column with **dual-Y charts**

I use google.charts.Bar but documents from [Google Charts](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart)  do not specify how to add label or text into **Dual-Y** Columns
[image: google chart physicals]

Thanks.

Comment: column labels are added via _annotations_ -- however, _material_ charts (`google.charts.Bar`) do not support _annotations_, see --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity #2143](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143) -- recommend using _core_ chart (`google.visualization.ColumnChart`) instead, with option --> `theme: 'material'`

Answer (score 0):

Now, this is possible, add in your chart options:

```
axes: {
    y: {
        time: { label: 'Per minute' }, // Left y-axis.
        temperature: { side: 'right', label: 'Fahrenheit } // Right y-axis.
    }
}
```

Please, see more details in [Google Chart documentation](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#dual-y-charts)